# React Button Boolean Value?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, button, boolean

first time posting here.. lol

I am new to React, and full-stack development in general, and I'm having a small issue with my code. I am designing a quiz, and I want the options (or answers) to be disabled once a user has selected an option (so once they've selected one of the options, they are unable to select another option).

```
checkAnswer(chosenAnswer) {
    if (chosenAnswer == this.state.answer) {
        alert('You have chosen the correct answer!');
        alert('Click Next to continue');
        this.setState({
            disabled: false,
            optionEnabled: false,
      });
        //alert(this.state.answerDetails);
    } else {
        alert('You have selected the wrong answer');
    alert('Click Next to continue');
        this.setState({
            disabled: false, //this is for the next button
            optionEnabled: false, //this is for the options which are designed as buttons
      });
    }}
```

I have a mechanism in place so that the "Next" button on the page is enabled only after an option is selected, and am trying to do something similar for the options, but not sure why it won't work. In the render function, I have..

```
              <button 
                optionEnabled={this.state.optionEnabled}
                onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(this.state.options.indexOf(option))}>
                {option}
              </button></td>
```

Further down, I have..

```
   <button
    className="ui inverted button"
    disabled={this.state.disabled}
    onClick={this.nextQuestion}
    
    >Next
    </button>
    }
           {currentQuestion === 7 &&
<button
  className="ui inverted button"
  disabled={this.state.disabled}
  onClick={this.lastQuestion}
>Finish Challenge!
</button>
```

At the beginning of my code, I have..

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  currentQuestion: 0,
  userInput: null, // user has not answered a question yet at the start
  points: 0,
  options: [],
  quizzes: {},
  **disabled: true,** // Next button is disabled by default
  **optionEnabled: true,** //options should be enabled by default
};
```

This is my lastQuestion function:

```
 lastQuestion = () => {
 //alert(this.state.wrongAnswer);
 //alert(this.state.answerDetails);
 if (this.state.currentQuestion === 7) { 
   this.setState({
     gameOver: true,
     disabled: false,
   });
 }};
```

Not sure why the enabling of the button for Next is working properly, but not for the options..

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Or if anyone can point me towards a resource that would help me understand the problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
optionEnabled={this.state.optionEnabled}
```

Should be this

```
disabled={!this.state.optionEnabled}
```

Comment: I have one more problem with the code which I will just post here as it is somewhat relevant to the initial question.
At the start of every Question, the next button is disabled as it should be, until an answer has been selected, which is fine. For the final question, instead of a "Next" button, there is a "Finish Challenge" button, and this should be disabled as well until an option has been selected, but this is not the case. Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: Hi, would need to see your code for that part to be able to help